# Funny behavior with html paragraph tags

Tags: php, html, regex, string

```
$regex = '#<p.+</p>#s';
```

My objective is to return the large string that occurs between the first paragraph tag, and the last paragraph tag. This is to include everything, even other paragraphs.

My regex above works for everything EXCEPT the paragraph tags. I tested it replacing the 'p' with 'html' and returned success, replaced with 'script' and returned success... Why would this return true for those cases but not for the paragraph?

I am still working on this, and relatively convinced that there is no strange escape sequence that is causing the regex to stop... I think this because I can extract everything between the first and last 'html' tag. The text between the 'html' tags also contains all of the 'p' tags that I am failing to extract. If there were some kind of escape or error, I think it would also throw the same error when extracting for the 'html' tags. I have tried preg_quote() with no success.

Perhaps I need to set memory devoted to regex processing higher so that it can process the whole document?

Update: In most cases the leading 'p' will (in most cases) NOT be the ending '/p' tag for the same paragraph tag.

Update: The returned results will be something akin to:

```
<p>this is the first tag</p>this is a bunch of text from the document, could be all manner of tags <p>this is the last paragraph tag</p>
```

Update: Code example

```
$htmlArticle = <<< 'ENDOFHTML'

Insert data from pastebin here
http://pastebin.com/4A3FYGc8

ENDOFHTML;

$pattern = '#<html.+/html>#s'; // Works fine, returns all characters between first <html and last /html
$pattern = '#<script.+/script>#s'; // Works fine, same as above
$pattern = '#<p.+/p>#s'; // Returns nothing, nothing at all. :'(

preg_match($pattern, $htmlArticle, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

?>
```

Solution:
    ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', '1000000');

I had exhausted my backtrack limit. This is a setting in your php.ini file, and can be set in code with ini_set(). Curiously, I set the value with ini_set() to match that in my php.ini file... So it should have worked from the start.  --- Thanks coming as soon as I can post a solution.

Comment: [Parsing HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I am not looking to parse the html into meaningful values. I am only looking to extract any text between the first occurrence of '<p' and last occurrence of '</p>'. Lets say for example's sake I will make a hash of the returned text and use it to encrypt something. Exactly what the returned text is I don't care for, as long as I get it.

Comment: You won't receive meaningful answers unless you give out actual details. Like what's the actual match result.

Comment: In most cases the leading '<p>' will (in most cases) NOT be the ending '</p>' tag for the same paragraph tag.

Comment: Maybe you need to explain again. The result is exactly what your regex should return, all content in between the first `<p>` and the `</p>` from the document end, or not?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your `'#<p.+</p>#s'` regex. It should work. Please include a more complete working example script in your question which exhibits the "funny behavior".

Comment: I am still working on this, and relatively convinced that there is no strange escape sequence that is causing the regex to stop... I think this because I can extract everything between the first and last 'html' tag. The text between the 'html' tags also contains all of the 'p' tags that I am failing to extract. If there were some kind of escape or error, I think it would also throw the same error when extracting for the 'html' tags.

Comment: You know you could always use [`preg_last_error()`](http://php.net/preg_last_error) and enable [`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/error_reporting) beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is very curious. It's not returning an error, and using a shorter document seems to return a match. I can't understand why this would happen. I've used regexes on enormous documents without trouble.

Note that this produces a match: `#<p\b.+<\#s`

Perhaps try playing with the [backtrack limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php), since there are many `</p>` matches. However if the limit were too low I would expect `preg_match` to return `False`, not 0!

As a workaround, try this instead:

```php
function extractBetweenPs($data) {
$startoffset = null;
$endoffset = null;
if (preg_match('/<p\b/', $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    $startoffset = $matches[0][1];
    $needle = '</p>';
    $endoffset = strrpos($data, $needle);
    if ($endoffset !== FALSE) {
        $endoffset += strlen($needle);
    } else {
        // this will return everything from '<p' to the end of the doc
        // if there is no '</p>'
        // maybe not what you want?
        $endoffset = strlen($data);
    }
    return substr($data, $startoffset, $endoffset-$startoffset);
}
return '';
}
```

That said, this is a very strange requirement--treating an arbitrary section of a structured document as a blob. Maybe you could step back and say what your broader goal is and we can suggest another approach?

Comment: Wow! Thank you. My next big step (after failing) was to write something that did just that. I will use your code, with maybe a few modifications.

Comment: As to my purpose: I am developing a process for scraping relevant content from various internet sites. I plan to archive these in order to capture "the internet on your birthday", and show users "what was up in cyberspace on their birthday". It was a fun little idea that ran me into this regex problem.

Comment: It looks like preg_match will return a true answer even if the backtrack limit is exhausted. That was my problem, which is solved now. The curious thing, is that I set the backtrack limit with set_ini() in the code to the same value as that in the php.ini file... REsetting it in the code made it work.

Comment: The problem with the segment you scrape is that it will not in any way be a valid html document. E.g.: `<div><p>para1</p></div><div><p>para2</p></div>` matches `<p>para1</p></div><div><p>para2</p>`. Maybe instead use the dom to capture all nodes between the first and last P element. That will at least be valid and won't cut off elements.

Answer (score -1):

Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML.

All you need is [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($your_html);
$node = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$dom2 = new DOMDocument();
$node = $dom2->importNode($node, true);
$dom2->appendChild($node);
echo $dom2->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I am not looking to parse the tags individually. I am looking to take the glob between the first occurrence of '<p' and last occurrence of '</p>', even if there are multiple paragraph tags in the document. I have used DOMDocument in the past, but it will not work for what I intend to do.